# What is the relation between a specifier and a determiner?

Tags: syntax, english, terminology, parts-of-speech, x-bar-theory

Does specifier mean "the" and "possesser" and determiner mean "the" and "possessive 's"?

Comment: 'Specifier' is just another name for 'determiner'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Determiner is a grammatical category for words like "the" and "a." Some theories claim that possessive 's is also a determiner.

Specifier is a grammatical relation in certain theories, such as X-bar theory. Determiners are frequently considered specifiers of nouns, although there are some people who follow the "DP-hypothesis" that the determiners are the heads, and nouns are the complements (another grammatical relation).

Answer (score 4):

The term *specifier* denotes a set position in a fixed schema, the X-bar schema. In contrast, the term *determiner* denotes a specific word category. The next illustration is from Wikipedia (X-bar theory):

[image]

The *spec* marks the specifier position. Often, a determiner occupies the specifier position (in the event that one is dealing with a noun phrase). Thus, in a noun phrase such as *the discussion of politics*, the determiner *the* occupies the specifier position and can hence also be viewed as a specifier. The possessive forms *my*, *your*, *his*, *her*, etc. are determiners like the definite article *the*, which means they also occupy the specifier position in noun phrases and can therefore also be viewed as specifiers.

In general, though, the X-bar schema is viewed as valid for all phrase categories, so in the event that one has, say, a clause at hand (instead of a noun phrase), the subject is positioned in the specifier position. Thus, an entire phrase can be viewed as a specifier.

Indeed, possessive *'s* can be viewed as the head of a determiner phrase, whereby it is then the entire phrase that is deemed to be a specifier. For instance, *Wilma's*, *my uncle's*, *the person we met's*, etc. are all headed by *'s* and can therefore be viewed as determiner phrases. It is these phrases that occupy the specifier position in the schema, not just *'s* alone.

In sum, the term *specifier* is a broader term than *determiner* insofar as a number of distinct word categories and even entire phrases can occupy the specifier position in the schema and hence be viewed as specifiers.

Comment: Thank you for the diagram.